# Edimax Dual WAN: how to sent trafic to a specific destination IP over a specific WAN interface?

Tags: ip-routing, wide-area-network

I have a Edimax BR-6624 Dual WAN router in my office. I've enabled load balancing to utilize both internet lines.

I want the router to use only one (specific) WAN interface when I connect to a specific IP. The reason is that the connection with the destination IP is much better through one of the two WANs. I dont know how to do this. Is it possible to do this with this kind of router?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be able to accomplish this using the "Routing" configuration.

The manual:
http://www.edimax.us/download/manual/BR-624724_Manual.pdf

On page 32 talks about routing.

They give static routing examples for internal networking, but I suspect it should work for external routing preferences too.

You should give that a try.

eg. For destination network blah/24 use nexthop of WAN1.
And then traceroute to check.

I would also like to put in a plug for pfSense http://www.pfsense.org/

If you don't mind getting your feet a little dirty, pfsense is known for being very good at doing the same things as the Edimax for much cheaper.

Comment: I've tried to use Static Routing with no success. It's only for LAN if there are other routers in the lan